# How will I make my app automaticly launch when I plug the USB

Tags: usb, launch

I put my programs into my USB. I want them to launch automaticly without asking when I plug the USB. Some of my programs are written in C and some are in Python. Is there a way to make it ?

Comment: Google is your friend.
Simple, easy guide:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Autorun-anything-off-of-a-usb-key/

Comment: wich OS? the user can always disable this feature. it would be a security issue if you could just do such things. btw. when you want to launch a python app, the user must have installed python.

Comment: For all popular systems, Windows Mac os x and especially Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows, I have done this using [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) (note that this feature does exist although does not appear in the description - you have to read all the release notes).